# how to open Md-dialog full screen angular4?

Tags: angular, angular-material2, mddialog

I am trying to pass some property value using config. But dialog not open into full screen.

```ts
openTwigTemplate(): void {
  let config = new MdDialogConfig();
  config = {
    position: {
      top: '10px',
      right: '10px'
    },
    height: '98%',
    width: '100vw',
  };
  const dailog = this.dialog.open(TwigDialogComponent, config);
}
```

How can I open dialog full screen based on resolution?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can add a `panelClass` to the dialog and then apply whatever css just to that specific dialog.

```ts
openTwigTemplate(): void {
  let config = new MdDialogConfig();
  config = {
    position: {
      top: '10px',
      right: '10px'
    },
    height: '98%',
    width: '100vw',
    panelClass: 'full-screen-modal',
  };
  const dailog = this.dialog.open(TwigDialogComponent, config);
}
```

*Create class:*

```css
.full-screen-modal .mat-dialog-container {
  max-width: none;
}
```

Comment: This code worked for me with maxWidth Set to 95vw `dialogConfig = {
            position: {
                top: '10px',
                right: '10px'
            },
            height: '98%',
            width: '100vw',
            maxWidth: '95vw',
            panelClass: 'full-screen-modal'
        };
`

Answer (score 48):

This work for me

```
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(CustomerGarageAddEditComponent, {
      maxWidth: '100vw',
      maxHeight: '100vh',
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%'
    });
```

Source

https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/9823

Comment: Actually this solution puts the dialog completely fullscreen.

Comment: Thanks, this is the simpliest solution.

Answer (score 7):

This works for me:

```ts
openTwigTemplate(): void {
  const dialog = this.dialog.open(TwigDialogComponent, {
    disableClose: true,
    panelClass: ['full-screen-modal']
  });
}
```

style sheet:

```
.full-screen-modal {
  max-width: unset !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  .mat-dialog-container {
    max-width: 100vw;
    max-height: 100vh;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    .mat-dialog-content {
      max-height: unset !important;
    }
  }
}
```